# Why path on server throw NullPonterException?

Tags: java, groovy, spock

I have a problem with the path to the file. Locally (Windows), the tests pass, but when I upload it to the server(Linux), I have:

`NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'text' on null object`

Sample code:

```
public final String MAIN = "dir1/dir2/dir3/"
public final String CAT_1 = MAIN + "subdirectory/"
```

somewhere in the method ...

```
def object = Utils.class.getClassLoader().getResource(CAT_1 + "file.xml").text
unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringSource(object), SomeClass.class).value
```

Comment: documentation of `getRosource()` states: "**Returns:** ... `null` if the resource could not be found ..." - so much probably `CAT_1 + "file.xml"` cannot be found, is not in given *package* (`ClassLoader.getResource()` searches resources using the CLASSPATH) [this comment is solely based on the question being tagged with the [tag:java] tag]

Answer (score 0):

> Why path on server throw NullPonterException?

`Utils.class.getClassLoader().getResource(CAT_1 + "file.xml").text` will throw a `NullPointerException` if `CAT_1 + "file.xml"` can't be loaded because `getResource` is going to return `null`.

Apparently that resource is not available at the path you are expecting it to be available at.